# How to fail Azure Data Factory pipeline based on IF Task

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline built on Azure data Factory. It has:

1. a "LookUp" task that has an SQL query that returns a column [CountRecs]. This columns holds a value 0 or more.
2. an "if" task to check this returned value. I want to fail the pipeline when the value of [CountRecs]>0

Is this possible?

Comment: Same thing I thought. But looks like there is no “Fail Pipeline” like there is one for Execute Pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably achieve this by having a Web Activity when your IF Condition is true ([CountRecs]>0) in which the web activity should call the below REST API to cancel the pipeline run by using the pipelinerunID (you can get this value by using dynamic expression - `@pipeline().RunId`)

Sample Dynamic Expression for Condition: `@greater(activity('LookupTableRecordCount').output.firstRow.COUNTRECS, 0)`

**REST API to Cancel the Pipeline Run**: POST [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelineruns/{runId}/cancel?api-version=2018-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/%7BfactoryName%7D/pipelineruns/%7BrunId%7D/cancel?api-version=2018-06-01)

MS Doc related to Rest API:  [ADF Pipeline Runs - Cancel](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/cancel)

One other possible way is to have an invalid URL in your web activity which will fail the Web activity in-turn it will fail the IfCondition activity, which inturn will result in your pipeline to fail.

There is an existing feature request related to the same requirement in ADF user voice forum suggested by other ADF users. I would recommend you please up-vote and/or comment on this feedback which will help to increase the priority of the feature request implementation.

ADF User voice feedback related to this requirement: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/38143873-a-new-activity-for-cancelling-the-pipeline-executi

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I simply called an invalid web url as suggested (the url is even descriptive eg: https://your_test_has_failed)

Comment: Hi KranthiPakala-MSFT, I followed your way of using web activity to cancel pipeline run but I am getting Authorization header missing error. I have clientId and clientSecret but I am still confused because that rest call needs token or authorization code. Please guide

Comment: The user feedback has been around for 2 years for this feature. So the only thing is to like you said make a workaround and use an Activity that is designed to fail on purpose.

Comment: Can you update the URL to the feature request, please?

Answer (score 1):

As a sort-of hack-solution you can create a "Set variable" activity which incurs division by zero if a certain condition is met. I don't like it but it works.

```
@string( 
  div(
    1 
  , if(
      greater( int(variables('date_diff')), 100 )
     , 0
     , 1
    )
  ) 
)
```